# Python reduce list by mask

Tags: python, list

I want to create a smaller list based on my mask: for example list `[1, 2, 3]` and mask: `[1, 0, 1]` should give me `[1, 3]`.

I have the written the following function:

```
def reducing(arr, mask):
    out = []
    for i in range(len(mask)):
        if mask[i]:
            out.append(arr[i])
    return out
```

Which works, but I think that it can be done simpler with reduce function (all in all - I am reducing the list :-) ) or with a comprehension. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress), like this

   ```
   >>> from itertools import compress
   >>> list(compress([1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 1]))
   [1, 3]
   ```
2. Otherwise, you can filter them with list comprehension, like this

   ```
   >>> [item for item, mask in zip([1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 1]) if mask]
   [1, 3]
   ```
3. Even simpler, instead of using `zip`, you can skip the items based on the index, like this

   ```
   >>> data, mask = [1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 1]
   >>> [item for index, item in enumerate(data) if mask[index]]
   [1, 3]
   ```
4. Or you can use simple looping with index, like this

   ```
   >>> [data[index] for index in range(len(data)) if mask[index]]
   [1, 3]
   ```